# com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.1.0-beta.1 error in androidx

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Why it's showing this error
When I tried to compile `com.Github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.1.0-beta.1`
this dependency it is showing this error

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.3.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.3.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.3.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.3.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.3.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.3.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.3.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.3.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.3.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.3.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.1) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)
```

here are my all dependency

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.4'
    implementation 'uk.co.samuelwall:material-tap-target-prompt:3.2.0'
```

anyone has any idea about this or do you know some other dependency for this. i am trying to load pdf file from server.

Answer (score 0):

In your gradle properties
add these two lines

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true

hope that will solve your issue

Comment: This is not a related answer